# java wrapper for .c code

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

I have the following c code:

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int add (int a, int b)
{
    a=4;
    b=4;
    return a+b;
}

int add_pointer (int *a, int *b)
{
    printf("values of a,b: %d,%d \n",*a,*b);
return ((*a)+(*b));
}

char* print_hello()
{
    return "hello_world";
}
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

int add(int a, int b);
int add_pointer (int *a, int *b);
char *print_hello();

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    char* rez;

    a=5;
    b=2;

    //int *r=&a;
    c= add(a,b);
    d=add_pointer(&a,&b);
    rez=print_hello();

    printf("sum is: %d and : %s %d \n",c,rez,d);
    return 0;
}
```

test_app.i

```
%module test_app

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```

I want to create a java wrapper ofer this .c code. I would like later to use this wrapper in an android demo.

I did the following:

```
$: swig -java test_app.i
```

**GIVES:**

```
test_app_wrapper.c
test_app.java
test_appJNI.java
SWIGTYPE_p_int.java 

$: gcc -fpic -c test.c test_app_wrap.c -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
$: gcc -shared test.o test_app_wrap.o -o libtest_app_wrap.so
```

UPDATE:

HelloWorld.java

```
      public class HelloWorld {
    native String print_hello(); /* (1) */
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("test_app_wrap"); /* (2) */
    }
    static public void main(String argv[]) {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
        helloWorld.print_hello(); /* (3) */
    }
}
```

When running:

```
$: javac HelloWorld.java 
$ java HelloWorld
```

I have:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no test_app_wrap in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1856)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:4)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure about the files generated? For me `swig` also generated `test_app.java` (yes, I've tried compiling your module).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to mention test_app.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `swig -java test_app.i`, it creates some Java glue classes that you must include in your Java project. The main interface generated is named `test_app.java` and looks like this:

```
public class test_app {
  public static int add(int a, int b) {
    return test_appJNI.add(a, b);
  }

  public static int add_pointer(SWIGTYPE_p_int a, SWIGTYPE_p_int b) {
    return test_appJNI.add_pointer(SWIGTYPE_p_int.getCPtr(a), SWIGTYPE_p_int.getCPtr(b));
  }

  public static String print_hello() {
    return test_appJNI.print_hello();
  }

}
```

As you can see, it delegates all the calls to `test_appJNI`, which is also automatically generated, and acts as a glue to the native code (using `native` methods):

```
public class test_appJNI {
  public final static native int add(int jarg1, int jarg2);
  public final static native int add_pointer(long jarg1, long jarg2);
  public final static native String print_hello();
}
```

So, you should:

- include both generated `.java` files in the project
- ensure that you load the `.so` library with `System.loadLibrary("test_app_wrap");` - you already do it
- simply call `test_app.print_hello()`

Also, recommended reading: [21 SWIG and Java](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html) section from SWIG manual. The *Preliminaries* and *A tour of basic C/C++ wrapping* sections explain all the basics quite well.

The error you get indicates that JVM can't load the `.so` library. My first question would be if it compiled and linked properly. If you are sure you have `libtest_app_wrap.so`, it might not be on the path where JVM looks for it (check this - http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_499.asp ). E.g. for me it was necessary to add `-Djava.library.path=.` to Java command line:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. HelloWorld
```

For reference - I've modified your `HelloWorld.java` file:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("test_app_wrap"); 
    }
    static public void main(String argv[]) {
        test_app.print_hello();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I did edit my question. Can you please take a look? WHat do you mean by import test_app? THANK YOU!

Comment: I mean plain old Java `import test_app;`.

Comment: Oh wait, you don't need to import explicitly (I haven't used Java for ages now).

Comment: Just finished editing my answer - I think it's enough details now!

Comment: Thank you very much! You are a true HELPER!! I modified the HelloWorld.java file and run java -Djava.library.path= .HelloWorld from command line, but I still have the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no test_app_wrap in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1856)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
 at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:3)

Comment: I MADE IT WORK!! It doesn t print any error messages, but test_app.print_hello() doesn't return the hello_world message. WHY?:( Do you have any ideea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26712/discussion-between-just-me-and-code-painters)

Comment: I'ma bit too busy now for chatting - but really, you should continue on your own now. And why you see no message? Because nobody is printing it - your `print_hello()` returns a string, so you can e.g. `System.out.println(test_app.print_hello());`. Good luck!

Comment: THank you very much!! You were right. I managed to make it work. I do have a problem when calling add_pointer(2,3). add_pointer(SWIGTYPE_p_int,SWIGTYPE_p_int) in test_app cannot be applied to (int,int)
 System.out.println(test_app.add_pointer(2,3));
                            ^

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't understand how jni works, check this tutorial:

[Calling C code from Java using JNI](http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jni/)

Your `test_app_wrap` doesn't exist, to use JNI you have to assign a particular name to your C functions, then make a Java class with native methods to call them i.e.

```
native String print_hello();
```

and, in the Java class, load the native library.

Then you will create a YourClass Java object and call the `print_hello()` native method

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay. When running swig -java test_app.i I get in return test_app_wrap.c, test_appJNI.java and SWIGTYPE_p_int.java. You are right about that native void print_hello. In my case print_hello method returns a STRING. I guess it will be native String print_hello(); Am I right?

Comment: Check the tutorial, it explains exactly what you have to do in order to get your JNI to work

Comment: I did check the tutorial. Thank you very much. In my case I do have the test_app_wrapper.c (created by swig). There is no need to create a new ctest.c (as it says in the tutorial). Could you tell me what is the path to the /path/to/jdk/headers ? Thank you!